# "Translate" a dataset for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am working on an application for Windows Phone 7.1 (outdated, I know) and I need to show information about different users, which is in a data base. The way I **have** to do it (schedules) is through a method in an ASP.NET web service that outputs a dataset. What I have in mind is that maybe there's a way to convert this data set into multiple strings, or even an array, just as long as Windows Phone 7 supports it.

So, how can I *translate* this dataset into a format I can work with?

The following is the web service method. Variables are in spanish and I rather not translate it and mess something up. Apologies for that.

```
public DataSet Listar_Usuario() //List_User
    {
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        abrirconexion(); //openconnection
        query.CommandText = "LISTAR_USUARIO"; //LIST_USER
        query.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        query.Connection = coneccion; //connection
        var_adaptador.SelectCommand = query; //var_adapter
        var_adaptador.Fill(DS, "Usuario"); //var_adapter
        query = null;
        cerrarconexion(); //closeconnection
        return DS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you **have** to use this method within the ASP.Net service? If not why not have a look at http://pcbl.de/2011/07/20/dataset-on-your-wp7-app/ - it should have everything you need to get around your problem.